# Javascript banner.innerHTML += "<div class='blocks'></div>" not working

Tags: javascript, html, loops, iteration, innerhtml

I have a web page and I needed to add HTML elements in a loop. But it won't add the HTML elements.

My HTML Code

```js
const banner = document.getElementsByClassName('banner');
const blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('blocks');

for(var i=1; i < 4; i++){
  banner.innerHTML += "<div class='blocks'></div>";
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Coming Soon</h2>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="blocks"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

But this is not working. Please help me to fix this

Comment: the clues in the name getElement**s* (plural)

Answer (score 0):

well `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object.
so you should like this

```
    const banner = document.getElementsByClassName('banner');
    const blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('blocks');
    
    for(var i=1; i < 4; i++){
      banner[0].innerHTML += "<div class='blocks'></div>";
    }
```

Comment: While array-like in many ways, the value returned by `getElementsByClassName` is a live node list and not an array.

Comment: Yes you are right. it returns an array-like object. thanks

Answer (score -2):

you can try API `document.querySelector(selector)`

```
const banner = document.querySelector('.banner');
const blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('blocks');

for(var i=1; i < 4; i++){
  banner.innerHTML += "<div class='blocks'></div>";
}
```